# How to concatenate 2 strings in SPD

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I am using `SharePoint 2013 workflow`, is there a way to `concat two string` variables?
I don't see an activity for it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SPD does not offer a concat function.

You can use SharePoint workflow variables and the **String Builder** dialog box in SharePoint Designer 2013 to be able to perform string concatenation.

[This](http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-concatenate-strings.htm) might help or check my steps below.

**Step One:** Create variables and put in a string.

[image]

Also CurrentItem can be used:

[image]

**Step Two:** Run the Workflow. Here my Output (Only the four variables in the StringBuilder):

[image]

If you think my answer is good, please give it a "vote up" or mark it as the answer if it fits perfectly for you.

Also uploaded a [blogpost](https://afrait.com/blog/workflow-to-concatenate-multiple-fields-en/) just now with a **Step-by-Step** "Storybook" of your question ;)

Comment: thanks for your reply, will it be possible for you to change the screenshots to english?

Comment: Did it. Check the pictures above.

Comment: thanks! Though instead of logging directly, you should set the final concat sting into a variable and then log. Anyways, it helped..:)